# JSF - Passing parameter between two RequestScoped Managed beans in JSF page

Tags: forms, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to think through an issue where a JSF page can pass a property of one managed bean into a property of another managed bean submitted through a form.  Both managed beans are to be RequestScoped to keep the application as simple as possible and move from one page view to the next - no Ajax.

Bean A

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanA implements Serializable{
private long ID;
private String name;

//code default constructor and getter/setter

public String viewBean(long ID){
    //set up a new beanA using ID argument and database call for the object beanA is based upon
    return "page2";
    }
}
```

Bean B (bean B has a property based on bean A ID)

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanB implements Serializable{
private long beanAnumID;
private String name;

//code default constructor and getter/setter

public String saveBean(long beanAnumID)
    //save the beanB.name and beanAnumID in database
    return "page1";
    }
}
```

Page 1 (where the details of Bean A are set; assume that bean A is created from a database in the server and then fed into the page - in the application, there can be several beans the user can choose from and this list of beans is rendered from a dataTable displaying a list of beanA's):

```
[.xhtml page content]

<h:form>
    <h:commandLink action="#{beanA.viewBean(beanA.ID)}" value="#{beanA.name}" />
</h:form>

[.xhtml page content]
```

Page 2 (this page will allow the user to name bean B and then have it persisted to DB once the form is sent back to the server):

```
[.xhtml page content]

<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="beanBName" value="#{beanB.name}" />
    <h:commandButton id="saveBean" action="#{beanB.saveBean(beanA.ID)}" value="Save Bean" />
</h:form>

[.xhtml page content]
```

The issue I have been running into is that when I submit the page2 form, it treats beanA.ID in the commandButton's action as a null pointer and the application crashes.  I would have thought that it would render it as a value when the page is created - I have also tried this as @ViewScoped and it still did not function properly.

It seems that this should be working; am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: @BalusC thanks for the link, using the params to pass the value into the method seems to be working; I tried using the inputHidden but noted from your post that it does not work in this instance and that the 'normal' html input type='hidden' should be used - why is that?

Comment: Using a ViewAccessScoped would make your application even simpler. No need to pass parameters on

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the feedback; that sounds like a better plan because I would like to avoid all the issue with using params - is ViewAccessScoped provided through the MyFaces CODI library?

Comment: DeltaSpike is a better choice... It's the successor to CODI and Seam