# Passing information between JSF pages

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am developing an application where I have to show data from the database based on User Input (let's say field empid for employee id and I show some information from database based on this input). I am using JSF, PrimeFace and Hibernate.

Now I have the index.xhtml page where I am taking input the empid. After that, I have to redirect to another page page2.xhtml.

Here is a snippet from index.xhtml:

```
     <h:form>
        <p>Employee ID:
            <p:inputText value="#{userBean.newuser.empid}" required="true"/></p>
     </h:form>
     <br />
     <h:form>
         <p:commandButton action="page2?faces-redirect=true" value="Enter" />      
     </h:form>
```

But after re-directing to page2.xhtml, the empid input from index.xhtml page is lost. I tried to read a few posts on this but was not able to understand. Please help. I am sorry if it is a repeated question.

Comment: Your input field and your command button are in different forms?

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I kept them in the same form but that too was no good.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147487/jsf-passing-parameter-between-two-requestscoped-managed-beans-in-jsf-page

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.tugay.biz/2016/06/jsf-post-redirect-get-with-view.html

Comment: @KorayTugay, Your example is working perfectly in transfereing the parameters from index to hello. Now, if I have to go from hello to hello2.xhtml, is there a way to preserve the values from index.xhtml into hello2.xhtml?

Comment: I do not know really..

Comment: does my answer help you finally ?

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you @ArturSkrzydło. I have marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that viewscopes of managed bean in which you are insterested in are `@RequestScope` ? You could specify more wide view scope for a managed bean, so it won't be destroyed after each request. However `@RequestScope` is really good when want to minimize session scope bloat. To stay with this session scope you could use *flash* object which was introduced with JSF 2.0. Thanks to this object you can transfer data between requests. You could put following code snippet :

```
ExternalContext.getFlash().put("empid", newuser.getEmpid);
```

in your `userBean`. After redirect you could retrieve that value on jsf page in the following way :

`#{flash.empid}`

Or in your managed bean :

```
ExternalContext.getFlash().get("empid");
```

More about flash with example can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194112/understand-flash-scope-in-jsf2) or in [JSF 2 Flash documentation](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/Flash.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. Will try this.

Comment: ViewAccessScoped from code works great to. Prevents 'sessionBloat' to a good extend and keeps your code simple...